# Is it possible to understand base64 encryptioned text?

Tags: encryption, base64

I have this text which is encrypted and in base64.
Is it possible to know what kind of encryption the text is encrypted with?

```
yIlK8dsGJq1uGsQn3Pr2pQ==
7EzRB7paOdpAuvquBDJFBQ==
dzwVgdpRkRCoSx210KYfIw==
dMDBsoNR+dO52HiTYk19FQ==
f2EhPe7F3EOmz1Z6pvcLdg==
CpRAXCGAuWFKHWmTDUvpQg==
nJHyAfK9cZ7+MzxcD8DUCg==
98W3idNGwTNHnQOMzguPHw==
SQ7qFl1NmX1WL9YtnysWWw==
Ns6S/417EGWWjT5ybAMWJA==
NY9gU3NxEfUygnmf18P9JQ==
hOS7+z6pZF3dVuF8BYmFVuCGhfdwThxM8hwCRFscsVI=
ajKZ7IpQS10Fu4jhsX9a0g==
mkgQ9bYZqbPLBK2Jo1Vnew==
XsxuWi2H8OIi/jGC22rtTWM6rckSWQI6eA8BP3qy5/4=
FzCVEidnanDeFcO3MvX6lQ==
ajI1SK0rq4axCglh5mWYIQ==
RYPXwMhpU0hxDZ1FC9YVJg==
mkFehbbPqE+v531TOTZOaA==
sCOzBRYq7VOQgA+gFDXlWw==
```

Comment: That's the point of encryption, isn't it? The ciphertext should not be intelligible and lead to the plaintext without using the key.

Comment: @ArtjomB. OP's question appears to be whether the *type* of encryption is determinable, i.e. "is this PGP?" sort of thing. They don't appear to be asking if it can be decrypted.

Comment: If you want to know what encryption is used do not look at the created output - reverse the used software instead.